# How to add pages in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is it possible to add more than one page to a QGIS print composer project? For example one sheet for the map and another sheet for the legend and some other information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You can change the number of pages in the print composer composition tab in "paper and quality" options.

[image]

From that point, you can put items in any of the pages. You can even put several maps if that fits your needs.

Comment: Cool Thank you Alexandre!! Is it alo possible to change page orientation for every page?

Comment: I', not sure... I believe you can't. But, as a workaround, remember that in QGIS 2.2 is possible rotate all composer Items, just rotate them 90º. Prepare your neck for it :-P

Comment: update: On QGIS 3 you can add pages with different orientation and size.

Comment: In QGIS 3, this is now done with the Layout menu> Add Pages...