# Adding multiple pages in QGIS print composer?

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3

Trying to add a separate page in QGIS 3. Since the composer was changed in QGIS 3.x.x I can't find the field for multiple pages that is listed here [How to add pages in print composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89575/how-to-add-pages-in-print-composer).

Where did it move?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can insert pages from `Layout -> Add Pages`

[image]

A new dialog will be appear to specify the number of pages and their locations:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the "Layout" menu, select "Add Pages" (or click the Add Pages button on the toolbar). You'll get a new dialog asking for the number of pages to add and their sizes:

[image]